# Given that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(f(x)+x^2)=l$ for a real number $l$, calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{f(x)}{1+x-x^2})$

Tags: limits, derivatives

Given that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(f(x)+x^2)=l$ for a real number $l$, calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{f(x)}{1+x-x^2})$.

Here are the steps I tried first:

1. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(f(x)) + \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(x^2)=l$
2. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(f(x)) + \infty=l$
3. Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(f(x))$ must be equal to negative infinity as this is the only way the sum in step 1 would result in a real number $l$ (using L'Hopital's rule).
4. From there, I saw that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{f(x)}{1+x-x^2})$ is indeterminate but, using L'Hopital's rule, we can differentiate the denominator and numerator twice to get $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{f''(x)}{2})$.
5. Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ was found to be $-\infty$, I assume the result of step 4 is $\frac{-\infty}{2}$, which is $-\infty$.

The problem is I'm making assumptions and I'm pretty sure my logic failed somewhere. Not sure how else to approach this problem; any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just notice that $f(x) = f(x) + x^2 - x^2$.  I should add that step (1) is incorrect.  You can only use $\lim(f(x) + g(x)) = \lim f(x) + \lim g(x)$ if both $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exist and are finite.  $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 = \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{1+x-x^{2}}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f(x)+x^{2}}{1+x-x^{2}}-\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x^{2}}{1+x-x^{2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x)+x^{2})\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+x-x^{2}}+1\\
&=l\cdot 0+1\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $l\neq0$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{f(x)+x^2-x^2}{1+x-x^2})=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{f(x)+x^2}{1+x-x^2}) -\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{x^2}{1+x-x^2})=1$$

Comment: Why do you rule out $l = 0$?

Comment: That is the easy case.

Comment: But the result is true, even if in that case.  You make it sound like the result fails for $l = 0$.

Comment: Sure! hence my saying "Hint:" The OP may fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\frac{f(x)}{1+x-x^2}=\frac{f(x)+x^2}{1+x-x^2}+\frac{-x^2}{1+x-x^2}$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)+x^2}{1+x-x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+x^2)\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+x-x^2}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x^2}{1+x-x^2}=1$.

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{1+x-x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)+x^2}{1+x-x^2}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x^2}{1+x-x^2}=0+1=1
$$

Comment: thanks for reminding